# components use flowlayout, but I am using GridBagLayouts

Tags: java, swing

My components are lining up like they are in a flowlayout. I add constraints to them, but it seems to not be following them, for what ever reason. I think I might be accidentally incorporating flowlayout somewhere, but I dont know where.

code:

```
    BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
       setLayout(borderLayout);
    //Initialize labels, text field, and combo box
     enterFirstName = new JLabel ("First Name");
     firstName = new JTextField();
     enterLastName = new JLabel ("Last Name");
     lastName = new JTextField();
     enterId = new JLabel ("Identification");
     identification = new JTextField();
     enterAddress = new JLabel("Address");
     streetAddress = new JTextField();
     enterCity = new JLabel("City");
     city = new JTextField();
     selectState = new JLabel("State");
     state = new JComboBox();
     enterZip = new JLabel("Zip Code");
     zipCode = new JTextField();
     enterPhone = new JLabel("Phone Number");
     phoneNumber = new JTextField();




    //Initialize buttons
     goBack = new JButton ("Go Back");
     purchase = new JButton ("Complete Purchase");
     cancel = new JButton ("Cancel");



     //making the grid thing
     dataPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

     GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

     c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
     c.gridx = 0;
     c.gridy = 0;
     dataPane.add(enterFirstName);
     c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
     c.gridx = 1;
     c.gridy = 0;
     dataPane.add(firstName);
     c.gridx = 0;
     c.gridy = 1;
     dataPane.add(enterLastName);

     dataPane.add(enterLastName);

     buttonPane = new JPanel();

     buttonPane.add(goBack);
     buttonPane.add(purchase);
     buttonPane.add(cancel);
     add(dataPane);
     add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}
}
```

Comment: You still have an open similar/same question that has not been resolved. Why are you asking this? Has that question been answered? If so, accept the answer to indicate this. Else let us know how it has not yet been answered.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels They took you advice, but either don't understand how `GridBagLayout` and constraints work or didn't look far enough forward into their code to realise their error...but agree, they should have accepted your answer...

Answer (score 2):

You're not supply constraints for the components...

```
 GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

 c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
 c.gridx = 0;
 c.gridy = 0;
 dataPane.add(enterFirstName); // ?? No constraints...
 //...
 dataPane.add(firstName);
 //...
 dataPane.add(enterLastName);
 // No idea why this is here...
 dataPane.add(enterLastName);
```

Make sure you supply the constraints you want to use...

```
 dataPane.add(enterFirstName, gbc);
```

Take a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details...

Comment: @user3026473 Good, make sure you mark HovercraftFullOfEels answer as correct when the little green tick becomes available to you...

Comment: Shoot, he hasn't even up-voted your answer yet much less accepted it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels We have long memories ;)